# How can I get the NSG of an app gateway in Azure if the name is not known

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I need to get the NSG an app gateway is connected to, I have the url it is listening for, any way I can get to the NSG by using just the name?

Comment: Do you want to get the NSG which attached to the Azure App gateway subnet? You could directly view it if you know the app gateway name in the Azure portal.

Comment: i know the app gateway name but cant see where to view the NSG?

Answer (score 0):

> I know the app gateway name but cant see where to view the NSG?

Just go to Application gateway dashboard and click the **Virtual network/subnet** in the right top corner, then you will navigate to the Virtual network page---settings---subnets. You will see the security group name attached to your app gateway subnet.